# Counterexamples to assertions about pointwise, uniform and integral convergence

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ and $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)\;\;,\;\forall x\in [0,\infty)$ and $f$ be integrable. Then
>
> $1$. $\int_{0}^{\infty}f_n dx\to\int_0^{\infty}f dx$
>
> $2.$ If the convergence is uniform then $\int_{0}^{1}f_n dx\to\int_0^{1}f dx$
>
> $3$. If the convergence is uniform then $\int_{0}^{\infty}f_n dx\to\int_0^{\infty}f dx$
>
> $4$. If $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f_n-f|dx\to 0$ then the convergence is uniform

Well, Only $2$ is correct in my knowledge about convergence of sequences of functions, but at the moment I have no counterexample to disprove the $1,3,4$ Could any one help me for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The following are guidelines to constructing counterexamples:

For 1: $f_n-f$ a triangular bump on $[n-1,n+1]$ of height $1$.

For 3: $f_n-f$ a triangular bump on $[n, 2n]$ of height $\dfrac 1n$.

For 4: $f_n-f$ a triangular bump on $\left[n,n+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right]$ of height $n$.

---

Bottom line: triangular bumps running to infinity are a good source of counterexamples.

Comment: The firsttime in my life sees picture of sequence of functions etc etc and pictures thank uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: Glad to spark a revelation :).

Comment: @Lord_Farin
In $4)$, unless I am wrong, in the example you gave $f_n$ does not converge pointwise to a limit function, does it? But the hypothesis in the question requires that it does

Comment: @Anu, it does. For any given point $x$, as soon as $n>x$, $f_n=f$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin You are right, thank you!