# integral from 0 to infinity of limiting function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If

$$f(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\cos(x)\over1+(\arctan(x))^n},$$
find integral the $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$.

I tried to put $\arctan(x)=t$ and transformed limits to 0 to $\pi/2$ and numerator became derivative of $\sin(\tan(t))$. Then I applied integration by parts but that leads me nowhere.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Very* bad idea. You can't exchange freely lim and integral (without uniform convergence). Start calculating
$$\lim_{n\to->\infty}{\cos(x)\over1+(\arctan(x))^n}.$$

Comment: Thanks...Now I did it. But please elaborate why my method was incorrect

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364398/counterexamples-to-assertions-about-pointwise-uniform-and-integral-convergence.

Comment: There's a theorem called [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) read it